# There isn't INSTALL PACKAGE on PACKAGE CONTROL (Sublime Text 2)

Tags: plugins, installation, sublimetext

(Operation System : Ubuntu)
I want to install [Sublime ALignment](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/alignment) plugin to my Sublime Text 2 .So, ı have installed [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) plugin with this :

```
import urllib2,os;pf='Package Control.sublime-package';ipp=sublime.installed_packages_path();os.makedirs(ipp) if not os.path.exists(ipp) else None;open(os.path.join(ipp,pf),'wb').write(urllib2.urlopen('http://sublime.wbond.net/'+pf.replace(' ','%20')).read())
```

But i couldn't install ALignment via Package Control. There isn't `Install Package` option on my Sublime Text 2.

Screenshot of Preferences > Package Control

[image]

Can you explain me how can i install [Sublime Alignment](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/alignment) (and other plugins) ?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem with ST2. It looks like it's something about localization, anyway, as a quick fix: just run "LANG=C" command before you start Sublime Text 2 from command line.

> aranel@aranel-desktop:~/Desktop/Sublime Text 2$ LANG=C
>
> aranel@aranel-desktop:~/Desktop/Sublime Text 2$ ./sublime_text

It should work correctly now :)

PS: In fact, you answered my question, Eray :) I was looking for a fix and just noticed Eray is a Turkish name too. And I noticed we have something in common :)

Comment: +1 nice psychic debugging/lateral thinking. glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

That's very strange.  Try removing Package Control from your Packages folder `(Preferences > Browse Packages)` and reinstalling.  Make sure you restart Sublime Text after you install it.  If it still doesn't appear, your best option is to contact Will Bond or file an issue on github (https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/issues).

Answer (score 0):

What I did is delete the entire Sublime Text 2 folder in  /Application Support/Sublime Text 2 and restart,reinstall